# Can I store JSON in a Azure Key Vault

Tags: json, azure, azure-keyvault

I have some JSON that I want to store in Azure Key Vault.

The data is not hierarchical just like this:

```
{
  "type": "XXXXXX",
  "project_id": "XXXXXX",
  "private_key_id": "XXXXXXXX"
}
```

But I have 4 sets of JSON Data and there are about secrets in each one, so I am hoping that I do not have to break these out into separate keys, but if I must I will do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this to be a valid statement to add a secret to an Azure Key Vault using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure):

`az keyvault secret set --vault-name "<YourKeyVaultName>" --name "AppSecret" --value "MySecret"`, taken from [Tutorial: Use Azure Key Vault with an Azure web app in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)

Building on this, I do not see any reason the value `MySecret` couldn't be a JSON string.

Investigating a bit further, have a look at [About keys, secrets, and certificates - Key Vault secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates#key-vault-secrets):

> From a developer's perspective, Key Vault APIs accept and return secret values as strings. Internally, Key Vault stores and manages secrets as sequences of octets (8-bit bytes), with a maximum size of 25k bytes each.

So as long as your JSON is under the 25k limit, you should be good to go.

Comment: @rickvdbosh can we have an example of that for example "OktaConfig": {
  "OktaDomain": "test",
  "ClientId": "test",
  "ClientSecret": "test",
  "redirectUrl": "test"
 }

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to properly escape the quotes (`` \`" `` = `backslash`, `backtick` & `double quote`) on the PowerShell command line in such a way as to satisfy **both** JSON and PowerShell formats for escaping quotes. Here is an example of how you would add your JSON string as the secret's value. Note the text in the `--value` has a `` \`" `` escape sequence for every quote that needs escaping.  [PowerShell needs](http://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm) the `backtick` to escape the `double quote` on the command line. A JSON string needs the `backslash` to escape a `double quote`. So, you get the `backtick` placed in-between the `backslash` and `double quote` (`` \`" ``) thus satisfying both PowerShell and JSON:

```
az keyvault secret set `
   --vault-name "<YourKeyVaultName>" `
   --name "AppSecret" `
   --description "An optional description" `
   --disabled false `
   --value "{\`"type\`":\`"XXXXXX\`",\`"project_id\`":\`"XXXXXX\`",\`"private_key_id\`":\`"XXXXXXXX\`"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this (as I was already getting the config from file) by using the --file argument instead. It saves the JSON exactly as it is in the file.

```
az keyvault secret set --name "<SecretKeyName>" --vault-name "<KeyVaultName>" --file "<RelativeFilePath>"
```